# Ruby on Rails multi word name model redirect error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created model named GroupEvent

When I tried to redirect it returns error. 
Here is code.

```
def create
  @ge = GroupEvent.new(groupevent_params)

  @ge.save
  redirect_to @ge
end
```

It shows such error. 
*undefined method `group_event_path' *

I think it should redirect_to groupevent_path but due to model name it throws error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: The redirect is correct. You have your routes set up incorrectly. Please add the relevant section of `routes.rb` to your question so we can identify the error.

Comment: resources :groupevents

Comment: What is the output of `$ rake routes`?  The correct path given your current route setup should be in the output

Comment: this is what I added in routes.rb

Comment: Try: 
   "rails routes | grep group".

You should see **group_event_path** in output.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to change:

```
resources :groupevents
```

to:

```
resources :group_events
```

`:groupevents` would imply a model named `Groupevents`. `:group_events`, implies a model named `GroupEvents`.

Also, it would be conventional to do something like:

```
def create
  @ge = GroupEvent.new(groupevent_params)

  if @ge.valid?
    @ge.save
    redirect_to @ge
  else
    redirect_to some_other_path
  end

end
```

In case there's something wrong with `@ge`.

Comment: OP should use scaffolding command in rails to avoid these type of naming issues

Comment: Using scaffolding is not always a good idea. It generates a lot of code at once and its easy to outrun your test coverage. @CarlosRoque

Comment: Personally (and this is just one dude's probably-terrible point of view), I ended up building my own scaffold because I feel the out-of-the-box scaffolding has bad practices built in. But, I'm probably insane.

Comment: @max respectfully, I think if you can't get your names correct from the get-go then scaffolding is a good a idea. specially for beginners. Obviously someone experienced will have no problem with doing things by hand. I find it easier to delete the files i don't need than having to figure out why a route is not working.

Comment: Please feel free to accept this answer if it worked for you. Cheers!